# How to know how many connections can handle my server

Tags: jakarta-ee, ubuntu, server

I have a JavaEE(JSF/EJB/JPA) + MySQL server and I would like to know how many connections can it handle at the same time. I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

```
maximum users connections  4,294,967,295
```

this is as provided by [MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections)[image]